# pickerInput showing numeric values instead of characters

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my dummy `dataframe` and variable social which hosts the unique texts to be populated in `pickerInput` in `global.R`

```
social_media <- c("Facebook","Instagram","YouTube","Snapchat","Twitter")
founder <- c("PersonA","PersonB","PersonC","personD","personE")
hits <- c(23,56,76,33,12)

DF <- data.frame(social_media, founder, hits)
social <- unique(DF$social_media)
```

in `app.R`, I have implemented `pickerInput` as follows:

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("pickerInput"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("social","social media", choices = social, multiple = FALSE, options = list(deselectAllText = TRUE,actionsBox=TRUE))
    )
    ,
    mainPanel() 
    ))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run the app, the list shows only values and not the texts. What could I be missing or not doing so as the choices appear?

[image]

Comment: Try this line of code `social <- as.character(unique(DF$social_media))`

Comment: does the answer below work for you? @Sayari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `social` is of type factor. That´s why  `pickerInput()` displays numerical output.

If you avoid creating factor:

```
DF <- data.frame(social_media, founder, hits, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

it will display the choices as characters.